# Display the "Devices and Printers" window via C#?

Tags: c#, windows

Using C#, how can I display the "Devices and Printers" window as shown in this screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

An application can open the Control Panel programmatically by executing `control.exe` [in a new process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191%28VS.85%29.aspx#canonical_names).  MSDN [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191%28VS.85%29.aspx#canonical_names) that the preferred method to invoke a control panel item is to use its canonical name, which is nonlocalized and stable across versions. Beginning with Windows Vista, each Control Panel item has a canonical name; MSDN provides [a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the standard Windows control panel items.  This list indicates that the canonical name for the **Devices and Printers** item is `Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters`.

Control panel items can be opened in a new process by invoking `control.exe` with the canonical name as a parameter (`/name <canonical name or GUID>`):

```
//note: assumes (using System.Diagnostics and System.IO)

string controlpath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System),
    "control.exe"); // path to %windir%\system32\control.exe
                    // (ensures the correct control.exe)

Process.Start(controlpath, "/name Microsoft.DevicesAndPrinters");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can open the Devices & Printers window by running the command `control printers` in a Command Prompt.

Knowing that, you can run `cmd` with the `/C` argument to tell it to run that command:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/C control printers");
```

If you'd prefer the Command Prompt not to show, you can use:

```
var Process = new Process();
var ProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/C control printers");
ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.StartInfo = ProcessStartInfo;
Process.Start();
```