# How do I programmatically set a a collection of default apps in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows

Every time Windows 10 updates it resets a series of default apps to Microsoft defaults. I want my videos and music handled by VLC and my photos by Irfanview. The MS default will not even give me good previews. After manually resetting default apps a few dozen times I am willing to write an app that runs in the background and protects my defaults - I understand Microsoft makes this difficult - does anyone know how.
I tried the registry changes here http://winaero.com/blog/prevent-windows-10-from-resetting-your-default-apps/. 
I tried Stop Resetting My Apps. I read this piece with a paragraph suggesting Microsoft will make this hard [Windows 10 equivalent of LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178986/windows-10-equivalent-of-launchadvancedassociationui). 
Does anyone have a solution - again I want something that can run in the background and set associations to my preferences not Microsoft's.

Comment: Not off hand, but my advice don't run in background, just run on startup.  Why waste the resources...

Comment: I have seem Microsoft code change preferences after a startup - say updating windows defender

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is over 5 years old, the SetUserFTA might help you.
See references [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/set-default-browser-file-associations-command-line-windows-10/) and [here](http://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/10/25/setuserfta-userchoice-hash-defeated-set-file-type-associations-per-user/).

It worked for me to to programmatically set the default browser in Windows 10 and it should work for any other file types.
I wrapped it in a BAT file, which I scheduled via Task Scheduler and I can also execute on-demand. Make sure to run it with elevated (highest) permissions, from your user account.